# Response status code changes after Application_EndRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, response, httpresponse

in C# ASP.Net REST application, in `Global.asax.cs` file, when I put a breakpoint in `Application_EndRequest` here:

```
namespace Proj1.Restful
{
    public class Global : BaseAPIGlobal<Proj1Context, Proj1Identity>
    {
        protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Put breakpoint here!
        }
    }
}
```

I keep seeing 200 as the response's status code in these objects:

```
(sender as System.Web.HttpApplication).Response.StatusCode
```

and

```
Context.Response.StatusCode
```

although the response's status code returned to the client is a different one, like 404 or 500 (which is the desired behaviour).

Where is the status code changes after `Application_EndRequest`?? Why can't I see the relevant status code on `Application_EndRequest`??

Thx in advance!

Comment: Are you using `Response.Redirect()` or `Response.End()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Nope... Any other ideas?
(Thx for your help)